# Extracting attributes out of json logs in DataDog

Tags: datadog

1. Some of our log lines look like:

   2023-11-09 13:26:00 [scheduling-1] INFO com.events.debeziumconnectorservice.debezium.Listener - {"MilliSecondsBehindSource":"1000836"}

Can I draw a graph where x-axis is time and y-axis is the value of MilliSecondsBehindSource?

2. Same question as 1) but now the log line looks like:

   {"MilliSecondsBehindSource":"0"}

I tried the following but no luck:

1. service:events-cdc-connector-stage | MilliSecondsBehindSource:*

Result: No hits

2. service:events-cdc-connector-stage | json "MilliSecondsBehindSource"

Result: No hits

3. service:events-cdc-connector-stage "MilliSecondsBehindSource"

Result: No hits

In our organization, devops has write access to DataDog and we devs only have ReadOnly access.

Thank you!